# Java- reading YAML file - Exception in thread "main" Cannot create property=Envs in reader

Tags: java, yaml

When loading a YAML file(using SnakeYAML) im getting an exception "Exception in thread "main" Cannot create property=Envs for JavaBean=com.java.Envs@3d82c5f3
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    Envs:
1)what im doing wrong? -env should start at the same location of Envs:?

`Envs:
  - env: "QA"
    firstName: "John"
    lastName: "Doe"
    age: 31
    contactDetails:
     - type: "mobile"
       number: 123456789
     - type: "landline"
       number: 456786868
    homeAddress:
      line: "Xyz, DEF Street"
      city: "City Y"
      state: "State Y"
      zip: 345657
  - env: "Dev"
    firstName: "John"
    lastName: "Doe"
    age: 31
    contactDetails:
       - type: "mobile"
         number: 123456789
       - type: "landline"
         number: 456786868
    homeAddress:
       line: "Xyz, DEF Street"
       city: "City Y"
       state: "State Y"
       zip: 345657`

I have the following classes for handling this YAML.

```
    public class Envs {
        List<Environment_Generic> envList;

        public List<Environment_Generic> getEnvList() {
            return envList;
        }

        public void setEnvList(List<Environment_Generic> envList) {
            this.envList = envList;
        }
    }

public class Environment_Generic {

    private String env;
    private String firstName;

    public String getEnv() {
        return env;
    }

    public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private List<Contact> contactDetails;
    private Address homeAddress;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContactDetails() {
        return contactDetails;
    }

    public void setContactDetails(List<Contact> contactDetails) {
        this.contactDetails = contactDetails;
    }

    public Address getHomeAddress() {
        return homeAddress;
    }

    public void setHomeAddress(Address homeAddress) {
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    }

}
```

Using the following code, im retrieving the details.

```
   public static Envs loadYAML(String file) throws IOException{

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Envs.class));
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/" + file));
        Envs envs = yaml.load(inputStream);
        return envs;
    }
Envs envs=loadYAML("test1.yml");
       System.out.println(envs.getEnvList().get(0).getHomeAddress().getCity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Documentation regarding typesafe collections](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-type-safe-collections), your document's root element is unnecessary. remove the root *Envs* parameter.

Currently, your object graph is a single List of *Environment_Generic* called *Envs*. However, all you want (and try to map) is the list itself.